# How to show ticks on log scaled Kivy Graph?

Tags: python, graph, kivy

If I plot a linear graph using Kivy Garden Graph, I can show x and y ticks/labels.  I can't find a way to label an axis if it is log scaled.

I have a MWE that plots a function on a y-linear and y-log graph, but the y axis labels won't show up on the log graph.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
import math
Builder.load_string("""
<MyLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10
    LinearGraph:
    LogGraph:
""")

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class LinearGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LinearGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.xlabel='X'
        self.ylabel='Y'
        self.x_ticks_major=25
        self.x_ticks_minor=5
        self.x_grid_label=True
        self.y_ticks_major=1
        self.y_grid_label=True
        self.xmin=0
        self.xmax=100
        self.ymin=0.1
        self.ymax=10
        self.ylog=False
        self.x_grid=True
        self.y_grid=True
        self.plot=MeshLinePlot(color=[1,1,1,1])
        self.add_plot(self.plot)
        self.plot.points=[(x, math.sin(x / 10.)+2) for x in range(0, 101)]

class LogGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LogGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.xlabel='X'
        self.ylabel='Y'
        self.x_ticks_major=25
        self.x_ticks_minor=5
        self.x_grid_label=True
        self.y_ticks_major=1
        self.y_grid_label=True
        self.xmin=0
        self.xmax=100
        self.ymin=0.1
        self.ymax=10
        self.ylog=True
        self.x_grid=True
        self.y_grid=True
        self.plot=MeshLinePlot(color=[1,1,1,1])
        self.add_plot(self.plot)
        self.plot.points=[(x, math.sin(x / 10.)+2) for x in range(0, 101)]


class MainscreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainscreenApp().run()
```

I would not expect the ticks to disappear - is there a problem with how I'm using the Graph class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to find the docs, but inside the code for `kivy.garden.graph`, it says:

> ```
> x_ticks_major = BoundedNumericProperty(0, min=0)
> '''Distance between major tick marks on the x-axis.
>
> Determines the distance between the major tick marks. Major tick marks
> start from min and re-occur at every ticks_major until :data:`xmax`.
> If :data:`xmax` doesn't overlap with a integer multiple of ticks_major,
> no tick will occur at :data:`xmax`. Zero indicates no tick marks.
>
> If :data:`xlog` is true, then this indicates the distance between ticks
> in multiples of current decade. E.g. if :data:`xmin` is 0.1 and
> ticks_major is 0.1, it means there will be a tick at every 10th of the
> decade, i.e. 0.1 ... 0.9, 1, 2... If it is 0.3, the ticks will occur at
> 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 2, 5, 8, 10. You'll notice that it went from 8 to 10
> instead of to 20, that's so that we can say 0.5 and have ticks at every
> half decade, e.g. 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50... Similarly, if ticks_major is
> 1.5, there will be ticks at 0.1, 5, 100, 5,000... Also notice, that there's
> always a major tick at the start. Finally, if e.g. :data:`xmin` is 0.6
> and this 0.5 there will be ticks at 0.6, 1, 5...
> ```

And the docs for `y_ticks_major` says:

> See :data:`x_ticks_major`

Note that if it is a `log` scale, then the value for `y_ticks_major` is not intuitive.

You can get ticks, labels, and grid on the `Y` axis by using the following values (for example):

```
    self.y_grid_label=True
    self.ymin=0.1
    self.ymax=10
    self.ylog=True
    self.y_grid=True 
    self.y_ticks_major=0.25
    self.y_ticks_minor=5
```